# Detecting whitespace in command line argument not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read in a command line argument to a python script and then detect if it has whitepaces or not. I have this so far...

```
import sys

arg = sys.argv[1]
if arg.isspace() == True:
    print ("Spaces detected")
```

But if I run the script with the following command then it does not detect that the argument has white spaces...

```
python myscript.py "my test agrument"
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: `if " " in arg:`

Comment: Tested that change. It works: https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/WelllitWelcomeAssociate#main.py (although you have to download it and run it)

Comment: isspace checks if in the string all characters are whitespaces ..

Comment: The documentation of [`str.isspace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) describes exactly what it does. Python has very good documentation and I suggest you make greater use of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand you do not want to use `isspace` but rather know if there are white space inside the string.

**Code not tested:**

```
import sys

arg = sys.argv[1]
if " " in arg:
    print ("Spaces detected")
```